# drawImage use SVG as image parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I use the `ctx.drawImage(image, dx, dy);` method for drawing a svg to my canvas.

Right now I get the SVG from the DOM and convert it to a base64 string to use it as `img.src = "convertetsvg"` after the `img.onload()`

Is there a way to use the SVG from the DOM **as** the actual image?

In this small example something like `image = this._$svgElement[0]` (This is what i aim for but I don't know how to do it or if it is even possible.) I know that the `drawImage` accepts `SVGImageElement` but I think that this is not the same as the `<svg>` from the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no interface to render a DOM document to the canvas. You must state an [image source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasImageSource).

`SVGImageElement` is the interface of the `<image>` element that you can use inside SVG content to reference an external image, just the same as you use the `<img>` tag in HTML.